# Provisioning issue in Xcode when using multiple configurations

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have 2 different schemes, pointing to two different bundle identifiers.

**com.myapp.appname**

**com.myapp.appname.Debug**

Each point to 2 different provisioning profiles.

Whenever I do a run on the scheme with the debug bundle id - I get an error saying my provisioning profiles bundle id (com.myapp.appname.Debug) does not match my apps bundle id (com.myapp.appname) - even though the bundle id that I'm currently building with is actually com.myapp.appname.Debug

To test further, I changed it to use the provisioning profile for com.myapp.appname

The build succeeded without error, but wouldn't install on the device because it was signing with invalid entitlements. Because the bundle ID of the app is actually com.myapp.appname.Debug

Any thoughts on why it is looking for the wrong bundle identifier during the code signing process?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using schemes for this instead of build configs?  If you're just changing simple things like icons, bundle IDs, code signing, etc., I think build configs are a much simpler, cleaner solution.

Comment: I am using build configs. I have a scheme that points to my DebugDEV build config on run. I use the schemes to be able to switch build configs.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use separate schemes for the build configs. Separate schemes are for when you need to generate different builds of the app the include different source files.

Comment: @nserror any fixes you would like to share. I am facing the similar issue

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. Changing the bundle identifier in my info.plist did not update the Product Bundle Identifier under packaging in Build Settings.

Change it there fixed the issue. Not sure if changing the bundle identifier in the info.plist should update that property or not. This is in Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: It will if you use the appropriate environment variable for it. If you manually entered the new bundle id, the two will not be linked and you'll have to update it in both places every time.